# Facebook linter not reading url

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am trying to figure out why facebook's [linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://tapawaydemo.atwebpages.com/tapaway_game.html) can not scrape my url.  The url is http://tapawaydemo.atwebpages.com/tapaway_game.html. The result is:

`Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.`

Even the url http://tapawaydemo.atwebpages.com returns the same result.

I am guessing the problem is either that my host has blocked access for facebook servers because it is a free tier, or that I am missing some required settings.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I added a bare-bones test page at http://tapawaydemo.atwebpages.com/fb_test.html.  The linter is [unable to scrape](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://tapawaydemo.atwebpages.com/fb_test.html) this page as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your sourcecode. For example, you open a button tag, but you use an anchor tag at the end instead of `</button>`.

edit:

Now that the problems are fixed, i tried the code on my own webserver because the FB Debugger just told me that the URL cannot be scraped. I know what the problem is now:

> URL Blocked:  Could not scrape URL because it has been blocked.

So, your domain seems to be blocked on facebook: "atwebpages.com" - Try to post your URL on your facebook wall and you will see. There will also be a link in the error popup then, which you can use if you think the link is ok.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, it was a remnant of having links instead of buttons for those functions.  I created a simpler page at (http://tapawaydemo.atwebpages.com/fb_test.html), which is also not being read by the [linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftapawaydemo.atwebpages.com%2Ffb_test.html). Is this a hosting issue?

Comment: I'm getting inconsistent results from the linter for the simpler page.  One time I got a 206 response, suggesting I explicitly set the og url and title tags.  The rest of the time I get the error that no data was scraped.  Any suggestions?

Comment: your meta tags are also wrong, they miss a slash at the end. should be like this: <meta property="og:title" content="My Title" />

Comment: The closing slashes are there: <meta property="og:url" content="http://tapawaydemo.atwebpages.com/fb_test.html" />